# How do i show dialog from code behind file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a web application in which multiple dialogs opens on one another.How to attach and show dialogs from cs file in asp.net web application so that the code becomes more manageable.

```
$("#dialog1").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    modal: true, 
    draggable: true, 
    height: 340, 
    width: 400, 
    position: "center", 
    resizable: false, 
    buttons: { 
        "Yes": function () { $("#dialog1").dialog("close") }, 
        "No": function () { } 
    } 
}); 
$("#btnDialog").click(function () { $("#dialog1").dialog("open"); });
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: I am opening dialog from jquery file

Comment: $("#dialog1").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        height: 340,
        width: 400,
        position: "center",
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {

            "Yes": function () { $("#dialog1").dialog("close") },
            "No": function () { }
        }
    }); $("#btnDialog").click(function () {

        $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
    });

Comment: How to attach and open same dialog to button from cs file.

Comment: Sounds like the root issue lies in your UI design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writting the js variable in code behind and use it in the page

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "ShowDialog", 
                 " var showDialog="+boolShowDialog, true);
    }
}
```

In page

```
<script>
if(showDialog==true){
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#dialog-box').dialog("show");

 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dialog-modal" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: gray;display:none">
        hi
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
```

Code Behind -

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool success = true;//set to true if save successful
        if(success)
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "testScript", " $(document).ready(function() { $('#dialog-modal').dialog();});", true);
    }
}
```